# Eliminar objeto de un array (RethinkDB)

Tags: nodejs

Trabajo con **Node.js**, estoy intentando eliminar un objeto desde mi base de datos RethinkDB, sin embargo, no sé qué métodos hay que usar para eliminar el objecto con la condición sea `id = index`, como lo hago en el siguiente código para editar un cierto objecto desde un array.

```
static async updateArray(table, id, uArray, index, doc) {
  if (typeof index === "number") {
    return r.table(table).get(id).update({ [uArray]: r.row(uArray).changeAt(index, r.row(uArray).nth(index).merge(doc)) }).run();
  }
  return r.table(table).get(id).update({ [uArray]: r.row(uArray).map(d => r.branch(d("id").eq(index), d.merge(doc), d)) }).run();
}
```

Sin embargo, ahora quiero lo mismo, pero eliminando el objeto de la misma manera que edito con el código de arriba. Por ahora el siguiente código funciona, pero me falta eliminar el objecto donde la condición `id = index` se cumpla.

```
static async removeFromArray(table, id, uArray, index) {
  if (typeof index === "number") {
    return r.table(table).get(id).update({ [uArray]: r.row(uArray).deleteAt(index) }).run();
  }
}
```

Adicionalmente: el uso que hago con **updateArray** es el siguiente: `.updateArray("localScores", this.guild.id, "scores", this.id, { score });`, que actualizaría la tabla `localScores`, obtendría el documento en el que la ID corresponda con `this.guild.id`, modificaría el array `scores`, obtener el documento cuya ID corresponda con `this.id`, y modificar el documento.

```
{
  "id": "256566731684839428",
  "scores": [
    {
      "id": "178951279190605824",
      "points": 2000
    },
    {
      "id": "251484593859985411",
      "points": 14300
    },
    {
      "id": "211591629486686208",
      "points": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

Pues ahora, lo que quiero es que con la función **removeFromArray**, pueda eliminar siguiente objecto:

```
{
  "id": "251484593859985411",
  "points": 14300
}
```

Es decir, al hacer `.removeFromArray("localScores", "256566731684839428", "scores", "251484593859985411");`, la función deberá eliminar del array dicho objecto. Y para ello, necesito que la función elimine el objecto del array en la que `id` sea igual a `251484593859985411`.

Comment: ahora mismo tengo el mismo problema, tu pudiste solucionarlo?
me dices como?

Comment: Sí, pude solucionarlo hace mucho tiempo ya, pero olvidé subirlo aquí. Ya está subido y con una explicación clara de cómo funciona el script que he escrito, @sofira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución: Accede a la tabla `r.table(table)`, obtén el documento a actualizar `.get(id)` y actualízalo `.update()`. Los parámetros a actualizar es el nombre de la propiedad del objeto que tiene el array a editar. Por ejemplo, si se llama `'scores'`, entonces vamos a editar `{ scores: [...{}] }`.

Ahora la parte divertida: Obtenemos la fila/propiedad `r.row(uArray)` que deseamos actualizar (`'scores'` en mi caso) y filtramos sus entradas `.filter(() => ...)`. La condición es que la propiedad `'id'` de cada objeto no debe ser igual al valor que deseamos eliminar, es decir, la variable `index`. Como resultado, el filtro debe ser `item => item('id').ne(index)`, es decir, que por cada item del array, que se acceda a la propiedad `'id'` y filtre aquellos cuyo valor no equivale a `'index'`, por lo tanto, tendrías como resultado el array pero sin el/los elemento/s cuya propiedad `'id'` es diferente al que se ha dado; dicho de otro modo, todos los elementos menos el que deseamos

```
/**
 * Borra un elemento de un array dado el documento seleccionado por su 'id', el nombre del array en cuestión, y la propiedad 'id' del objeto dentro del array.
 * @param {string} table El nombre de la tabla.
 * @param {string|number} id La ID del documento a actualizar.
 * @param {string} uArray El nombre de la propiedad del documento el cual contiene un array.
 * @param {string} index El valor de la propiedad 'id' que debe tener el objeto a ser borrado del array.
 * @returns {Promise<Object>}
 */
removeFromArrayByID(table, id, uArray, index) {
    return this.db.table(table).get(id).update({ [uArray]: this.db.row(uArray).filter(it => it('id').ne(index)) }).then(resolvePromise);
}
```